# Excel Charts, add custom forecasting line

Tags: excel, charts, customization, forecasting

I got the following graph (in purple):

[image: Chart to show the current and wanted state]

Now I want to add the dotted forecasting line.
It's a cell value, but not referenced to the point on the X-Axis (Oktober 13).

I am a bit lost as to how I could accomplish it. Anyone got an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What "it's a cell value"? Slope? X-Y or line graph?

Comment: The forecasted value is written in a cell. It should be an Y-value of presumably a second graph. My original thinking was, that I add a second line graph with the Y plot points for September 13 and the forecast number, but I cant match them with the X plot points, namely September 13 and Oktober 13, because they dont correspond.
But X-Y Plot might be an interesting idea, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

As I responded to this exact question in the [Mr Excel forum](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/732826-excel-chart-add-another-line-show-custom-made-forecast.html#post3606559):

Use data like this and make a simple line chart:

```
  Date        Actual   Forecast
10/1/2012      1650
11/1/2012      1050
 5/1/2013      1100
 6/1/2013      1125
 7/1/2013      1400
 8/1/2013      1100
 9/1/2013      2200      2200
10/1/2013      1450      2450
11/1/2013
12/1/2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved (in my case with Excel 2007) but proved to be rather fiddly and I would not recommend an x-axis with irregular time intervals:

[image: SO19377713 example]

Basically a Stacked Line chart, with November 13 and Dezember 13 data points formatted for Line Color No Line and one of the Oktober 13 data points formatted with a different Line Style.

A question like this might be better suited to [Super User](https://superuser.com/) where, if you are lucky, you might attract Jon Peltier's attention.